How to Manually Update Microsoft Office 2021 on Windows Server 2019 Without Internet Access?
In our organization, we are using Windows Server 2019 and have installed Microsoft Office 2021. Our server lacks internet connectivity, and we need to update Microsoft Office 2021 to address several CVEs. Despite our efforts, we couldn't find and download the exact KB files on the Microsoft website, and the specific updates required are not clearly mentioned by Microsoft. We need to apply the following updates:
Outlook 2021 Version 2304 (Build 16327.20214):

CVE-2023-36568 (Elevation of Privilege)
CVE-2023-36413 (Security Feature Bypass)
CVE-2024-20677 (Remote Code Execution)

Excel 2021 Version 2304 (Build 16327.20214):

CVE-2023-24953 (Remote Code Execution)
CVE-2023-33162 (Information Disclosure)
CVE-2023-33161 (Remote Code Execution)

Word 2021 Version 2304 (Build 16327.20214):

CVE-2024-21379 (Remote Code Execution)
CVE-2023-36009 (Information Disclosure)
CVE-2023-29335 (Security Feature Bypass)

Microsoft Office 2021 Version 2304 (Build 16327.20214):

CVE-2024-21413 (Remote Code Execution)
CVE-2023-36897 (Spoofing)
CVE-2023-36895 (Remote Code Execution)
CVE-2023-29333 (Denial of Service)
CVE-2023-27911 (Buffer Overflow)

For example, I attempted to find the download link for CVE-2023-36568, but it wasn't available. The same issue occurred with all the other CVEs; there were no download links provided for Office 2021. I did find some Office 2016 download links for certain CVEs, but none for Office 2021.
Does anyone know how to find and download the exact KB articles for these CVEs and manually install the updates on our offline server? Any specific troubleshooting steps or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Office 2021 Update history https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2021. Microsoft Update Catalog https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx And why not just keep your office updated to the latest version so you're most protected ?

You may also use ODT tool download the Office 2021 installation files to your internal network. Then Office will  check updates regularly. To change the update source path, you may use group policy, the reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/updates/change-update-channels. To specify the version number of Office, you may add "Version attribute (part of Add element)" in .xml file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office-deployment-tool-configuration-options#version-attribute-part-of-add-element

Thank you for your valuable response. I used the methods outlined in the following links to update Office 2019 offline using the Office CDN method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ltsc/2021/deploy                                                    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/installation/product-ids-supported-office-deployment-click-to-run
